# React: A service returning a ui component (like toast)?

Tags: reactjs

Requirement: Show toast on bottom-right corner of the screen on success/error/warning/info.

I can create a toast component and place it on any component where I want to show toasts, but this requires me to put Toast component on every component where I intend to show toasts. Alternatively I can place it on the root component and somehow manage show/hide (maintain state).

What I am wondering is having something similar to following

```
export class NotificationService {
    public notify = ({message, notificationType, timeout=5, autoClose=true, icon=''}: Notification) => {
        let show: boolean = true;
        let onClose = () => {//do something};
        if(autoClose) {
            //set timeout
        }
        return show ? <Toast {...{message, notificationType, onClose, icon}} /> : </>;
    }
}
```

And call this service where ever I need to show toasts. 
Would this be the correct way to achieve the required functionality?

Comment: If you are interested, there's a library that I tend to use for toasts in my applications: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyHaber, just had a look that looks good but I am more interested in understanding if people use such patterns where a service returns a ui component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppContext to manage the state of your toast and a hook to trigger it whenever you want.

ToastContext:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

export const ToastContext = createContext();

export const useToastState = () => {
  return useContext(ToastContext);
};

export default ({ children }) => {
  const [toastState, setToastState] = useState(false);
  const toastContext = { toastState, setToastState };
  return <ToastContext.Provider value={toastContext}>{children}</ToastContext.Provider>;
};
```

App:

```
<ToastProvider>
   <App/>
   <Toast show={toastState}/>
</ToastProvider>
```

Then anywhere within your app you can do:

```
import {useToastState} from 'toastContext'
const {toastState, setToastState} = useToastState(); 
setToastState(!toastState);
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution, so in a way the Toast has to be placed somewhere, we really cant have a service that can place toast in component tree on the fly.